# Singular and Plural - When Asking People

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I find it complicated when addressing to a group. I'm pretty sure that when I use "people" it's plural and when I use "everyone" it's singular then. But I'm confused about the things that come after that.

Here's an example of mine:

> 1.) People, get your bag/s (assume each person only has one bag) and hit (a) rock/s (assume they all have to hit one rock, not as a team but individually) using your own burger/s! (assume each one has one burger)
>
> 2.) What if we change "people" to "everybody"? Would the answers be the same?

Comment: It's a vague area, since in the real world if you're telling multiple people *collectively* to do something, you're *also* simultaneously giving the instruction ***to each individual addressee***. Most people would say [*Everybody raise your right **hand***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22everybody+raise+your+right+hand%22) (24 hits in Google Books), but I think it would be pedantic in the extreme to object to [*Everybody raise your right **hands***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22everybody+raise+your+right+hands%22) (that's ***3*** hits).

Comment: ***In colloquial usage, everyone and everybody is used with their, theirs***. However, people is always plural. (no s  in the verb).

Answer (score 1):

1) **People, get your bags** (bags, because there are bags for each and every person) **and hit [the rock / a rock]** (it's not clear from the context whether they all should hit the same rock (the) or one/any rock (a); not rocks, as this would mean that they should hit several rocks) **using your own burgers!** (again, plural, as you are referring to a number of people with their burgers)

2) Everyone, get your bag and hit [the/a] rock using your own burger!

Comment: So, I should use **a rock** even though it would count to more than one rock when each one of them hit one rock.

Comment: I would say so, because otherwise it might be understood that everyone should hit several rocks.

Comment: Well, yeah, but if you don't it might be misunderstood they all just have to hit one rock, as a team not each one of them, when you mean the contrary.